# Vector going out of bounds

Tags: c++, vector

I'm attempting to iterate through a list of 6 'Chess' pieces. Each round they move a random amount and if they land on another then they 'kill' it.

The problem is that when the last piece in my vector kills another piece I'm getting a vector 'out of range' error. I'm guessing it's because I'm iterating through a vector whilst also removing items from it, but I'm not increasing the count when I erase a piece so I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my vector:

```
vector<Piece*> pieces;
pieces.push_back(&b);
pieces.push_back(&r);
pieces.push_back(&q);
pieces.push_back(&b2);
pieces.push_back(&r2);
pieces.push_back(&q2);
```

and this is the loop I iterate using:

```
while (pieces.size() > 1) {
    cout << "-------------- Round " << round << " --------------" << endl;
    round++;
    cout << pieces.size() << " pieces left" << endl;
    i = 0;
    while (i < pieces.size()) {
        pieces.at(i)->move(board.getMaxLength());
        j = 0;
        while (j < pieces.size()) {
            if (pieces.at(i) != pieces.at(j) && col.detectCollision(pieces.at(i), pieces.at(j))) {
                cout << pieces.at(i)->getName() << " has slain " << pieces.at(j)->getName() << endl << endl;
                pieces.at(i)->setKills(pieces.at(i)->getKills() + 1);
                pieces.erase(pieces.begin() + j);
            }
            else {
                j++;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

**Solution**

```
pieces.erase(pieces.begin() + j);
break;
```

Comment: This is what a debugger is for. Use your debugger, observe the values of `i` and `j`, and how the vector's size changes, and why, and the bug should be obvious. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer. No exceptions. P.S. You may even see the bug before the critical `at()` blows up. Observe how, as if by magic, on the next iteration of the outer loop, `pieces.at(i)` is not the same piece as it was on the previous iteration of the loop, and ask yourself: how did that happen?

Comment: Check [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/28998/) in order to safely delete items from a vector while iterating over it

Comment: Doesn't your design of this program take in consideration what piece is at a certain position?  If so, why do you need to search what the piece is that needs to be "killed"?  In other words, why do you need the second `while` loop?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie to check all pairs i think

Comment: This whole collision logic is very confusing.  What makes the `j` item erased, but not the `i` item?  Why is the `i` item "stronger" than `j`?  I think that is where the trouble starts, and that is not having a coherent set of rules in place.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That is because in Chess the piece that is landed on is the one that is removed from the board.

Comment: @bobnog So why are you starting `j` back to 0 on each iteration?  If you do that then `i` is potentially greater than `j`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *stronger* is a very good word here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie probably we both have missed this line `pieces.at(i)->move(board.getMaxLength());`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a very strong feeling that this line of code:
>
> ```
> i++;
> ```
>
> is your culprit which is missing either a needed break condition or another conditional check that is missing from your loops. As it pertains to your nested while loops' conditions since they are based on the current size of your vector and are not being updated accordingly.
>
> ```
> while (pieces.size() > 1) {
>     // ...
>     while (i < pieces.size()) {
>         // ...
>         while (j < pieces.size()) {
>               // ...
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> This is due to the fact that you are calling this within the inner most nested loop:
>
> ```
>  pieces.erase(pieces.begin() + j);
> ```

---

You are inside of a nested while loop and if a certain condition is met you are then erasing the object at this index location within your vector while you are still inside of the inner while loop that you never break from or check to see if the index is still valid.

Initially you are entering this while loop with a vector that has 6 entries, and you call erase on it within the nested loop and now your vector has 5 entries.

This can reek havoc on your loops because your index counters `i` & `j` were set according to the original length of your vector with a size of `6`, but now the vector has been reduced to a size of `5` while you are still within the inner most nested loop that you never break from nor check to see if the indices are valid. On the next iteration these values are now invalidated as you never break out of the loops to reset the indices according to the new size of your vector, nor check to see if they are valid.

---

Try running this simple program that will demonstrate what I mean by the indices being invalidated within your nested loops.

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> words{ "please", "erase", "me" };

    std::cout << "Original Size: " << words.size() << '\n';
    for (auto& s : words)
        std::cout << s << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    words.erase(words.begin() + 2);

    std::cout << "New Size: " << words.size() << '\n';
    for (auto& s : words)
        std::cout << s << " ";
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

*-Output-*

```
Original Size: 3
please erase me
New Size: 2
please erase
```

Comment: Your code was very useful, thank you. You were right about needing a break point, I tried them in a couple of different places but after the pieces.erase(pieces.begin() + j); line was where it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic needs a little refinement.

The way you coded it, it seems the "turn based" nature of chess has been replaced by a kind of "priority list" -- the pieces closer to the start of the vector are allowed to move first and, thus, get the priority into smashing other pieces.

I don't know if you want this logic to be right or wrong. Anyway, the trouble seems to be due to unconditionally executing the line

```
i++;
```

It should not be executed if you remove a piece for the same reason 'j++' isn't executed: you will jump over a piece.

Answer (score 1):

You should save locally `pieces.at(i)` and use this local variable everywhere you use `pieces.at(i)`.

To avoid both elements out of bound and logical problems you can use `std::list`.

As aside, you should use `std::vector<Piece*>` only if these are non-owning pointers, otherwise you should use smart-pointers, probably `unique_ptr`.

Comment: if j starts at i+1 then won't the collision detection ignore all the pieces that are before it in the vector?

Comment: @bobnog yes, but if `detectCollision(a,b)` returns the same result as `detectCollision(b,a)` then it doesn't matter because these pairs already have been considered.

Comment: I've tried running the code with j = i+1 now and it gets no errors, but it seems to be ignoring the collision detection when queen2 makes a move

Comment: @bobnog try the first option. `auto cur = pieces.at(i)`. And use this local variable.

Comment: @bobnog yeh, i missed this line `pieces.at(i)->move(board.getMaxLength());`. The second option is not an option here. Sorry for that.